# #1093 - You can't specify target table 'comments' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I want to delete duplicate comments from my database

```
Delete FROM `comments` WHERE id IN 
(
  SELECT id
  FROM comments
  GROUP BY 
  COMMENT , course_id
  HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
)
```

I got error #1093 -

> You can't specify target table 'comments' for update in FROM clause.

how can I modify my query to work fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: how can I modify my query to work fine

Answer (score 1):

Try aliasing the sub query:

```
Delete FROM `comments` WHERE id IN 
(
  select id from (
      SELECT id
      FROM comments GROUP BY  `COMMENT` , course_id
      HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
  ) as comm
)
```